# How do I backup Google Authenticator on my iPhone?

Tags: backup, iphone, authentication

In 2022 I bought an iPhone 13 Pro Max. I had had an iPhone 12 Pro Max. I factory reset my iPhone 12 Pro Max and gave it to a friend who had lost his phone. My iPhone was doing a daily cloud backup. I had set up my new phone using my old phone. I thought everything was fine until I realized I had destroyed my Google Authenticator App and there seemed to be no getting it back.

I was surprised. I had set up my new iPhone using my old iPhone. I do a daily phone backup. It did not occur to me that this would not also backup my Google Authenticator App.

So now having had this experience of having wiped out my Google Authenticator app on my iPhone, I want to backup my Google Authenticator app's data, the eight accounts I multifactor authenticate against using Google Authenticator app on my iPhone.

I have Googled it, I have checked Google help and I can't seem to find the information I want which is, how do I backup Google Authenticator app on my iPhone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google authenticator blank after backup restore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308131/google-authenticator-blank-after-backup-restore).  Also see:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/260032/119271

Answer (score 3):

It is by design that Google Authenticator was not included in your backup - this is a decision made by Google.

Initially there was no way of getting account information out of Google Authenticator, but back in December 2020 they added a feature to help you get account data out of the app - for example for when you get a new phone. It is still a manual process though.

You start with the old phone that has the account information in Google Authenticator. Open the app, tap "Exports Accounts" and select the accounts to export - and it will show a QR code (or more).

Then on the new phone, install the Google Authenticator app and tap "Import existing accounts". Now you can scan the QR code(s) off the old phone to transfer the account information.

For backup purposes, you could copy the QR codes (i.e. screenshot or similar) and store them somewhere secure if you ever need to import them again on a new device.

Comment: I am surprised and disappointed that Google did not provide a backup mechanism for authenticator accounts. I tried, did what you suggested. I created a QR code to export all of my accounts. I then exited Google Authenticator and used that QR code to put my authenticator code on my iPad.

It worked.

Thank you.

I will try this from now on, exporting my codes, creating a QR code and using that as my backup. I wish Google would provide us with a proper backup mechanism.