# How do I recover my accounts with Google Auth after my phone died? [I have my codes]

Tags: iphone, google, google-apps, two-step-authentication

I've done a bunch of googling and I find it difficult to find answer to this question.

Here's the story. I had Google Authenticator set up on my iPhone. I used it to verify login for a bunch of accounts, including crypto accounts like Coinbase, Kraken and Nexo.

Then my iPhone spontaneously died.

I have a new iPhone now. How do I set up the Google Authenticator app so that it recovers those linked accounts? (Coinbase, etc).

I'm not sure if I'm wording this correctly, so forgive me.

I have my Google back codes. I would think that those could be used to login to the app, no? And to recover my accounts?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/260032/274411

Comment: I'm not writing as an answer since I don't use Google Authenticator, but... 1) your Google backup codes will only help you into your Google account, not Google Authenticator. 2) Unfortunately you'll probably need the backup codes you were issued when you set up 2FA. I don't believe Google Authenticator syncs/backs up to anything.